# how to display the hidden value of client secrets in azure app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Here I am using this command to set credentials

```
az ad app credential reset --id "$getAppId" --append --credential-description "Test is sample2"  --end-date '2299-12-31' --password "Test123"
```

but I need client secrets value should display on azure app registrations UI
Here the value is hidden as you can see in below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is that you can't. A client secret value is only displayed at the time of creation and after that it is neither displayed nor it can be retrieved.

What you would need to do is create a new client secret and copy its value when it is displayed.

**UPDATE**

So I took your code and ran it against my Azure AD application:

```
az ad app credential reset --id "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" --append --credential-description "Test is sample2"  --end-date '2299-12-31' --password "Test123"
```

and this is shown in the output:

```
> The output includes credentials that you must protect. Be sure that
> you do not include these credentials in your code or check the
> credentials into your source control. For more information, see
> https://aka.ms/azadsp-cli


{
  "appId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "name": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "password": "Test123",
  "tenant": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

As you can see the password I am setting is shown in the response.

Comment: As per you when we create for 1st time it should display the value and after refreshing, it will show the value as Hidden, and here when running the command for the first time it shows me value as hidden